# Problems updating to React 15.4.0

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm getting this error with in all my files:

```
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react/lib/ReactMount' in...
```

I'm using the latest version of react: 15.4.0.

webpack: 1.12.11

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems seems to be located in [react-hot-loader](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader) library.

As mentioned @gaereon in my [react gitub](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8302#issuecomment-260979568) post, apps should not rely on internal APIs. So, react-hot-loader is [using](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/417) ReactMount.

I asked to fix it, for now I will return to latest version of React.

**UPDATE**

I had the 1x version. I switched to 3x beta version and works fine.

Answer (score 1):

One quick solution to this will be use `npm` to install `reactjs`.

```
npm install --save react react-dom
```

Don't use standalone react bundle.

More solutions can be provided if you post your `webpack` config file.

Comment: Hi, I used npm to upgrade it.